# Matching a filename on python

Tags: python

I have multiple files in a, some of them are named 'network.log', while others are named something like network-wTHz.log. The last four characters after hyphen keeps changing. What is the wildcard can I give to match both files? I am using following if statement:

```
if current_file == 'network.log' or current_file == 'network-*.log':
     curr_file_path = dir_path + str('/') + str(current_file)
```

Above code works fine, but it only looks for network.log. It doesn't find any files with pattern network-xxxx.log.

Comment: if the codeblock you've presented is inside a loop over all filenames, you might want to try looping over `glob.glob('network*.log')` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if current_file.startswith('network') and current_file.endswith('.log')
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. What module startswith and endswith is taken from?

Comment: `startswith` and `endswith` are both part of the `str` API (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions.

```
import re  
if re.match("^network(-.*).log$", current_file):
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `glob`, it is designed for this stuff:

```
import glob

for file_with_path in glob.iglob('/path/to/directory/network*.log'):
    print(file_with_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do in the pythonic way. Use glob

```
import glob
glob.glob('network*.log')
```

The above code returns a list of files matching the pattern